# C++ : For loop not iterating designated number of times (1 iteration less)

Tags: c++, xcode, for-loop, vector, iteration

I have a for loop and a variable C. 
The loop begins at 0 and is expected to run C times but actually it runs C-1 times.

Here is my code :

```
    vector<int> v(1000) //Allocated globally



    int M, S, C;
    cin>>M>>S>>C;
    //cout<<M<<" "<<S<<" "<<C;
    int fi=0, la=0;

    for(int i=0; i<C; i++)
    {
        int f;
        cin>>f;

        if(i==0l){ fi = f;}
        v[f] = f;
        cout<<i<<" "<<f<<" "<<v[f]<<endl;
        if(i==C-1){ la = f;}
    }
```

This is my test case -

```
3 27 16 
        2 
        3 
        5 
        6 
        8 
        9 
        10 
        13 
        14 
        15 
        16 
        19 
        20 
        21 
        22 
        27
```

Output by Xcode :

```
    0 2 2
    1 3 3
    2 5 5
    3 6 6
    4 8 8
    5 9 9
    6 10 10
    7 13 13
    8 14 14
    9 15 15
    10 16 16
    11 19 19
    12 20 20
    13 21 21
    14 22 22
```

I use Xcode on Mac if it makes a difference.
The variables fi and la are to find the first and the last element of the list.

I want to know what is wrong in my code for the for loop and why is it not iterating C times.

Thanks

Comment: @JonnyHenly (i < C) means that i is always less than C during execution of the loop

Comment: If `C` is 3 you start at zero and iterate with values 0, 1, 2 - that *is* *3* times.

Comment: We need more information in regards to what `C` is actually is or contains. Right now, your code iterates counting from `0 to C-1`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl : as per OP's test case, output ends at 14, not 15 as expected for C = 16.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes I know that, but before downvoting if somebody sees the output in the question you shall notice that the last value of i is 14 and not 15. It should be 15. This is my question!

Comment: Cannot reproduce [Demo](https://ideone.com/r0So2k).

Comment: @ShreeyashGotmare: What is `v`? By leaving it out, your test case runs till and including 15 as expected. I'm speculating here, but if `v[f]` throws...

Comment: If that is your question, then why didn't you include it in your question?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Done. (On a sidenote, it might be obvious.)

Comment: Xcode wanted to me to hit the return button to get the last iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop *is* iterating `C` times. This is the classic [Zero-Based Numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) issue.

Let me explain using your example where `C` is *16* and a numbered list:

1. 2
2. 3
3. 5
4. 6
5. 8
6. 9
7. 10
8. 13
9. 14
10. 15
11. 16
12. 19
13. 20
14. 21
15. 22
16. 27

So you see your lopp *did* iterate 16 times. To go from *0* to *16* would have actually been iterating one more time, so *17* times.